# How to optimise memory in my Sencha Touch app?

Tags: optimization, popup, listener, sencha-touch, carousel

I have just started learning Sencha Touch and I love it so far. I have started building thumbnail carousel gallery with a popup that appears on touching each thumbnail. So far so good, it works as expected. However I am conscious that the way I have coded some things may not be best practice. I have watched all the tutorial videos.

Basically I have added an event listener to each thumbnail (so far I have 8 thumbnails, and 8 listeners)...that trigger 8 separate popup windows.

I think there must be a better way of doing it, perhaps having one listener on the body of the carousel, and 1 popup perhaps with a template function, that calls variables from elsewhere. Would that be the correct way of doing it? I also read somewhere to save memory it is best to define the popup right after the listener, so that it doesn't get loaded straight away.

Here is the code of one of my popups (I have defined 8 of them):

```
 var popup1 = new Ext.Carousel({
        floating: true,
        modal: true,
        centered: true,
        padding: 5,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,            
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                title: 'Slide 1',
            }
        ],
        items: [
            {
                html: 'This is a test',
                }, {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                html: '<img src="cricket.jpg"/>',
                }, {
                title: 'Tab 3',
                html: '3'
                }]
            });
```

and here is my carousel code:

```
 var carousel1 = new Ext.Carousel({
        defaults: {
            cls: 'card'
        },
        items: [{
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="1.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup1.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }
                },{
                    flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="2.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup2.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }
                }]
            },

                {
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="3.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup3.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }
                },{
                    flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="4.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup4.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }
                }]
            },
            {
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="5.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup5.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }
                },{
                    flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="6.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup6.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }
                }]
             },

             {
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                {   flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="7.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup7.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }
                },
                {   flex: 1,
                    html: '<img src="8.jpg" />',
                    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(c){
            c.body.select('img').on('click', function(e, t){
                popup8.show('pop');
            });
        }
    }

                }      ]
             }   


            ]},
         ]
    });
```

Would I be better off putting the popup code after the listener do you think?

Thanks a lot,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more reading, it seems that I need to get a better understanding of event delegation.

I'm pretty sure best practice would be to put 1 listener on the carousel, instead of multiple click listeners on each thumb. Sencha mentions something like this:

```
listeners: {
body: {
    click: myHandler,
    delegate: 'img'
}
}
```

...so do you think the best place to put this listener would be at the top of the carousel, after this bit?

```
var carousel1 = new Ext.Carousel({
    defaults: {
        cls: 'card'
    },
```

Eventually I would like to populate the thumbnail images using AJAX and a tpl (template) but I havn't got that far yet!

:-)

Si